# Отладочная база данных

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

Создал две базы данных. Одна из них - отладочная, в ней я создаю структуру таблиц, пишу хранимые процедуры и представления, а также на ней отлаживаю клиентские приложения. Вторая база - рабочая. С ней работают готовые клиентские приложения. Допустим, я разработал какой-то новый функционал: написал несколько хранимых процедур и внёс изменения в клиентское приложение. Как перенести все изменения DDL в рабочую базу? Есть ли какие-то автоматические средства для этих целей? И вообще, верна ли такая архитектура в принципе?

Используемая СУБД - PostgreSQL.

Comment: База данных используется совместно с каким-то приложением или имеет несколько приложений-клиентов? Обычно используют механизм миграций, который позволяет воспроизвести структуру базы данных в любой момент.

Comment: @cheops, есть несколько клиентских приложений. Про миграции сейчас почитаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Один из вариантов автоматизации процесса переноса структуры БД и хранимок — использовать систему управления версиями. Бывают специализированные системы для баз данных вроде [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/).

Схожие вопросы уже обсуждались, например, здесь: [dba.se](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/62143), [so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846659/how-can-i-put-a-database-under-git-version-control)

Comment: К сожалению, liquibase не выгружает функции. Сейчас ещё испытаю flyway.

Comment: Кажется, я не сразу понял принцип таких систем. Оказывается, они не могут сгенерировать скрипт, переводящий базу данных из предыдущего состояния в новое. Требуется самостоятельно писать последовательность таких скриптов-коммитов и накладывать их на базу с помощью этих систем.